# How to check orientation based on css `transform: rotate(270deg)` in Cypress?

Tags: rotation, orientation, cypress, e2e-testing

I need to check the orientation of a div with Cypress.

This is the test:

```
cy
  .get('data-test="vertical"')
  .should('have.css', 'transform', 'translate(-100%, 0) rotate(270deg)')
```

The div behaviour is standard in a scenario, or it's rotated with css `transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(270deg);` in the other scenario.
I need a way to check the orientation, but `transform` is difficult to check, because for example in Cypress test what happens is:
when I expect `transform: rotateX(180deg)` I actually receive `transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1.22465e-16, 0, 0, -1.22465e-16, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`.

I need to find a smart way to detect the orientation. Suggestions? Tips?

Comment: If you are getting `matrix3d` out from `translate` & `rotateX` but don't know how they relate, observe and create a mapping between the two formats. How are you querying?

Comment: So due to this error `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<div>' to have CSS property 'transform' with the value 'translate(-100%, 0) rotate(270deg)', but the value was 'matrix(-1.83697e-16, -1, 1, -1.83697e-16, -71, 0)'` shall I find a mapping between `transform: translate(-100%, 0) rotate(270deg);` and `transform: matrix(-1.83697e-16, -1, 1, -1.83697e-16, -71, 0);`

Comment: Yes, well create a mapping function that takes the values you know as input (translate & rotate) and outputs the matrix3d values, then write something like `expect(actual).to.equal(transformMappingFn('translate(-100%, 0) rotate(270deg)'))`. Only works if there a small number of transforms on the page.

Comment: BTW what is the actual test?

Comment: I added the test in the content of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is solved like this, with the creation of a command:

```
const getTransformRotationAngle = (cssTransformMatrix, absoluteValue) => {
  const cssTransformMatrixIndexes = cssTransformMatrix
    .split('(')[1]
    .split(')')[0]
    .split(',')
  const cssTransformScale = Math.sqrt(
    cssTransformMatrixIndexes[0] * cssTransformMatrixIndexes[0] +
      cssTransformMatrixIndexes[1] * cssTransformMatrixIndexes[1]
  )
  const cssTransformSin = cssTransformMatrixIndexes[1] / cssTransformScale
  const cssTransformAngle = Math.round(
    Math.asin(cssTransformSin) * (180 / Math.PI)
  )
  return absoluteValue ? Math.abs(cssTransformAngle) : cssTransformAngle
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getTransformRotationAngle', getTransformRotationAngle)
```

and its use in the test:

```
cy
  .get('data-test="vertical"')
  .invoke('css', 'transform')
  .then(cssTransform => {
    cy.getTransformRotationAngle(cssTransform, true).should(
      'eq',
      90 || 270
    )
  })
```

Comment: Looks good, but be aware some of the numbers are floating point and may not pass 'eq' matching. BTW what is "90 || 270"? Does that mean either 90deg or 270deg, or is 90 the -100% translate?

Comment: well, question is about vertical orientation, so I accept both orientation of 90 and 270 degrees. in the solution I apply the absolute value to avoid the minus (-90). not total strict, but for vertical detection is enough

Comment: `const cssTransformAngle = Math.round(Math.asin(cssTransformSin) * (180 / Math.PI))` this makes it round so float are not an issue (hopefully)

Comment: I didn't have many cases to check, but it worked fully for me